# CommandBehavior.SchemaOnly fails for some stored procedures

Tags: stored-procedures, ado.net, idbcommand

Making an ADO.NET call to run a stored procedure using `IDbCommand.ExecuteReader(SchemaOnly)` and it throws an exception if the stored procedure uses a temp table. The exception is "`Invalid object name '#tempPCBBHolidays'."` (that's the name of the table).

So...

Is using `CommandBehavior.SchemaOnly` a bad idea for stored procedures? If so, when all I need is the metadata should I use `CommandBehavior.SingleRow` instead?

Or should I put the call in a try/catch and only on an exception switch to `SingleRow`? (This is for a SQL tool we ship so I don't know what stored procedures will be called.)

Or is there another approach that is better?

thanks - dave

Answer (score 1):

[According to the MSDN forum](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e43a5e0c-baad-4f3e-9e55-9fabb72d2c16/commandbehaviorschemaonly-fails-for-some-stored-procedures?forum=adodotnetdataproviders), this is a known problem with Sql Server. The solution is to call again requesting SingleRow.